# employee attendance structure using 3 table left innerjoins

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT b.Device_Person_ID, a.Personal_id, Date1, 
CASE WHEN b.Device_Person_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END as Emp_Status
FROM Emp_setting a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT device_person_id, MAX(logDateTime) AS Date1 FROM tempDeviceLogs
GROUP BY device_person_id) b
ON a.personal_id = b.device_person_id
```

---

here i joined only two tables but i need to join 3 tables to show employee details with attendance with specific date.

Required output is

employeename device_person_id designation emptype status

---

'dbo.persons_profile table

```
[pesonal_id]
,[Emp_Code]
,[Title]
,[First_name]
,[Middle_name]
,[last_name]
,[Father_Husband_Name]
,[Dob]
,[Age]
,[gender]
,[Marital_status]
,[Nationality]
,[bloodGroup]
,[perAddress]
,[PerStreet]
,[PerLocation]
,[PerCity]
,[PerPincode]
,[CorAddress]
,[CorStreet]
,[CorLocation]
,[CorCity]
,[CorPincode]
,[LandlinePhone]
,[cellNo]
,[EmailId]
,[NosofDependendants]
,[Dependendants_details]
,[Emergency_FirstName]
,[Emergency_Middle_name]
,[Emergency_Last_name]
,[Emergency_WithRelation]
,[Emergency_PhoneNo]
,[Emergency_CellNo]
,[Emergency_emailId]
,[Office_PF_ac_no]
,[ESI_ac_no]
,[JoinedDate]
,[Photofile]
,[ReportTo]
,[Brief_Notes]
,[dateofTermination]
,[termination_note]
,[Print_Priority]
,[DeviceEmployeeID]
,[LogsPermitted]
,[Machin_install_id]
,[Designation]
,[Dept]
,[Section]
,[Groups]
,[EmpWorkingTypeT]'
```

---

dbo.tempDeviceLogs table

```
[LogsID]
,[Device_Person_id]
,[Device_id]
,[logDateTime]
,[logVerifyMode]
,[workCodeID]
,[Machin_install_id]
,[data_loaded_dt]
,[Inout]
```

---

dbo.Emp_setting table

```
[Empset_id]
,[personal_id]
,[DesignationID]
,[DivisionID]
,[Emp_status]
,[Emp_TypeId]
,[Dept_Id]
,[Group_Id]
,[NDIVGRP_CODE]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write to join conditions for achieving what you required.
as an example:

```
SELECT a.<respective>_id, d.<respective>_title, s.<respective>_id
FROM Emp_setting a
INNER JOIN persons_profile s ON a.<respective>_id = s.<respective>_id
INNER JOIN Emp_setting      d ON a.<respective>_id   = d.<respective>_id
INNER JOIN tempDeviceLogs       b ON s.<respective>_id   = b.<respective>_id
```

Comment: that's okay.but what about employee attendance status how to specify it.